# ImportError: No module named allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have installed django-allauth for using social accounts in my django app but every time I try

> manage.py syncdb

It gives me an error

> ImportError: No module named allauth

I tried to add even

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

to

```
manage.py
```

but its still not working.I am unable to debug about how to add path to allauth to include it?

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: using pip install django-allauth

Comment: could you provide the full traceback? Do you have `django.contrib.sites` in `INSTALLED_APPS` earlier than `allauth`?

Comment: Actually the problem is if I install django-allauth in virtualenv manage.py syncdb does not work but if I install package in system it works

Comment: yes I have django.contrib.sites installed earlier than allauth

Comment: You run the syncdb inside the virtualenv?

Comment: yes for some apps I work completely in virtualenv

Comment: try importing it in python shell..

Comment: I mean if you run the manage.py like this: /path/to/your/.virtualenvs/project/bin/python /path/to/your/manage.py syncdb. Also, you have installed South?

Comment: it does work when you install it in your vitual environment. check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

go to the root of the folder where you have your virtual environment and type:

```
source bin/activate
```

Comment: how do you know he's even using virtualenv?

Comment: I had to actually deactivate and install this app from outside my environment for some reason. This only happened on Windows. Works as it should on Mac and Linux